# Very slow wifi connection Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, 15.04

I recently bought a laptop and installed new Ubuntu on it, dual booting with Windows 8. In windows I have a very decent wifi connection and signal is always high. However on Ubuntu at the same Location in my house I only get 1 or 2 bars. I tried to post it's number but it seems I don't have no wireless extensions in iwconfig

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"amiraratoud"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 94:FB:B3:F9:94:2D   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

and lspci results:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Camarillo Device (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 0a)
0a:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1347 (rev a2)
```

and lshw -class network results:

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: d8:5d:e2:b8:12:0f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=*.*.*.* latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:18 memory:c6100000-c6107fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0a
       serial: 94:57:a5:d6:b7:0f
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8107e-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:49 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c6004000-c6004fff memory:c6000000-c6003fff
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: first of all, run the following command: `sudo iw dev wlan0 set power_save off`

Comment: Also, what about *actual* network performance? just because it only shows 2 bars and it shows 3 or 4 on windows means almost absolutely nothing in terms of actual network performance.

Comment: Additionally, what you see with no wireless extensions in iwconfig are network interfaces that are not wireless. wlan0 is wireless and the other two are not

Comment: finally, you might get better performance at a distance after running the following command: `sudo iwconfig wlan0 retry 12`

Comment: tnx for your time @mchid I did all of them and problem solved. actually my problem was inconsistent internet speed where it was often so slow while I have a good internet speed in general. I think power options solved the issue. in case i have internet speed drop downs what do u suggest?

Comment: plzz sir I'm still facing the problem nothing actually has changed since then. what kind of information can I give you to see what's causing this? @mchid

Comment: one thing first, you will have to repeat those commands after you reboot because they will reset. Also, see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Comment: that sounds like it might be interference from neighboring frequencies, run that script and post the results and we'll see

Comment: Tnx m8, here it is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12941343/ @mchid

Comment: Hi, I sent u guys the test results. plz it's just unusable specially when I'm downloading stuff it just takes forever. @mchid

Comment: First, try setting your router to use channel 6 as there are a lot of neighboring networks on channels 1 & 11. The firmware for your card doesn't have the interference mitigation that it does with windows so it's best to use a less used frequency. Let us know if this works .